# Retain the rows of duplicates it is duplicate on other column else retain the row which has highest value on other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A",98,56,3],["C",18,45,8], ["B",79,54,36], ["A",98,56,2],["C",18,45,9],["B",79,54,36], ["A",98,56,1],["B",79,54,36],["C",18,45,7]], columns=["id","c1","c2","c3"])
```

Need to check for duplicates on id,c1,c2 columns, if duplicates found check values in c3 for those rows, if they are not the same(duplicate), retain the row which has the highest value in c3 and delete other rows. If the value in c3 is the same don't delete those rows.

```
Output = pd.DataFrame([["A",98,56,3],["B",79,54,36], ["C",18,45,9],["B",79,54,36], ["A",84,65,6],["B",79,54,36]], columns=["id","c1","c2","c3"])
```

How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `transform`

```
out = df[df.c3==df.groupby(['id','c1','c2'])['c3'].transform('max')]
  id  c1  c2  c3
0  A  98  56   3
2  B  79  54  36
4  C  18  45   9
5  B  79  54  36
7  B  79  54  36
```